# how to send request payload in json data using post method

Tags: java, web-services, http-post

```
String pay= "["
            + "{"
            + "\"internalAssessmentResponseId\" : \"Mer\\/ccclsv__AC1B752E-D079-4BA9-AA4F-46E1F8DDC11F__3048\","
            + "\"responses\":["
            + "{"
            + "\"assessmentCreatedDate\":\"2016-11-25T11:35:54\","
            + "\"responseData\":[],"
            + "\"assessmentId\":\"943\","
            + "}"
            + "],"
            + "\"addtionalInformation\":[],"
            + "\"emailId\":\"lucky@me.com\","
            + "\"salesTeam\" :\"\","
            + "\"demographic\": {"
            + "},"
            + "\"repId\":\"AJMA-OG9OMQ\","
            + "\"assesseeId\":\"AGHA-2D0FVL\","
            + "\"assesseeType\":\"CONTACT\","
            + "\"typeOfResponse\":\"iPad\","
            + "\"userTimeZone\":\"a\""
            + "}"
            + "]";

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
       PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://signature");
       post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(pay, "application/json", null));    
       httpclient.executeMethod(post);
       String jsonResponse = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
       jsonInsertRes = jsonResponse;
       System.out.println("Response in create==>"+jsonResponse);
      }
 catch (MalformedURLException e) 
  { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
  catch
  (IOException e)
  { 
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
       return jsonString.toString();        
    }
```

I am getting wrong response like this
Can not construct instance of org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@11ff00b3; line: 1, column: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending JSON string as a string form parameter 
and then on server read the JSON string value and convert the string to a Java Object(say object of Message.java as for example).

Message msgFromJSON = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSONString, Message.class);

I have tried few times and it worked fine.